# The FileZilla can only work once

Tags: crash, filezilla

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.5 as a virtual machine on VMware. I've encountered a serious problem when using FileZilla. It only can be initialized once when the pwd is `~/.config/filezilla/`. If I exit FileZilla and initialize it once again, the terminal is stuck on reading locale option from `~/.config/filezilla/filezilla.xml` and the system crashes like this:

[image]

The first initialization would even crash if the pwd is not `~/.config/filezilla/`.

I have removed and reinstalled FileZilla many times, but I cannot fix this problem.

Comment: Might be better to get help from the filezilla support site. Also please do not post pictures of text include the text in the question.

Comment: I supplement more details. Yesterday, FileZilla could be initialized once when pwd was the home directory.  However, after I removing the FileZilla icon from the favorites tab, things get what I post above.